# GCC doesn't find an existing header file

Tags: gcc, cygwin, header-files, libtool

I am trying to compile [pkcs11-helper](https://github.com/OpenSC/pkcs11-helper) under Cygwin with GCC. After configuring I called make. These are the last lines of its output:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../include -I../include -I/usr/include  -g -O2  -MT _pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/_pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.Tpo -c -o _pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.lo _pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -I../include -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT _pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/_pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.Tpo -c _pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/_pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.o
_pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.c:57:26: fatal error: openssl/x509.h: No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't GCC find my `/usr/include/openssl/x509.h` (which definitely exists)? As you can see I even passed `-I/usr/include` (there will be the same message without it).

This is the corresponding line 57 in `_pkcs11h-crypto-openssl.c`:

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
```

Comment: Did you give it a try by giving `-I/usr/include/openssl` instead ?

Comment: Yes I did. Same error.